# Am I able to change source and destination IP address on packet when output source depends on input destination IP?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

I have a Linux server which is used to change the source and destination IP addresses.

I was trying to set it up so it accepts packets with an destination IP of `X.X.X.11 - X.X.X.15` and changes any of these to one destination IP address (ex. `Y.Y.Y.11`).

When received, I started to set it up so that in Prerouting it changes the destination IP.

Then I wanted to have it also change the source IP in Postrouting but came across the problem that what I want to change the Source IP address to depends on what the original destination IP address was.

This is not going to work the way I've been trying to set it up because I have now rewritten the destination and lost what the original was.

Is there a different way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The man page indicates that the `conntrack` module can do this:

> **conntrack**
>
> This module, when combined with connection tracking, allows access to the connection tracking state for this packet/connection.

> [**!**] **--ctorigsrc** address[/mask]
>
> [**!**] **--ctorigdst** address[/mask]
>
> [**!**] **--ctreplsrc** address[/mask]
>
> [**!**] **--ctrepldst** address[/mask]
>
> Match against original/reply source/destination address